# Explain ㅎ being silent in Korean language

Tags: phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, korean, phonotactics

A: Between vowels, /h/ may either be voiced [ɦ] or become inaudible or disappear often.

B: Intervocalically, it is realized as voiced [ɦ], and after voiced consonants it is either [ɦ] or silent.

Some speakers articulate 기회, 생활, 사랑해요, 후회 as 기외, 생왈, 사랑애요, 후외.

What phonological rules are there behind all of these articulation?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common phonological process - [assimilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)), whereby one phoneme takes on properties of nearby phonemes.

In this case, the voiceless glottal fricative [h] takes on the property "voiced" from the vowels on both sides (or a preceding⟨ŋ⟩in words like 방학 [paŋɦak] to become the voiced glottal fricative [ɦ].

If the ㅎ ceases to be pronounced at all, it is a case of [elision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision).